# What makes this polynomial a square number?

Tags: mathematics, number-theory

For which integer values of $x$ is $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ a square number? Please include a proof that the polynomial cannot be a square number if $x$ is not one of your answer(s).

---

Source: a math olympiad prep question in *Math Letter Vol.1* (1988), KAIST math problem solving club.

Comment: An interesting note is that you can turn the cyclotomic polynomial equation into Bring-Jerrard form $u^5-u+(k^2-1)/k^{5/2}=0$ where $x=u\sqrt k$ and $k$ natural.

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3975198/given-that-p-is-a-prime-and-the-sum-of-all-positive-divisors-of-p4-is-a-pe/3975208#3975208)... Don't see why this is fit for puzzling over math.

Comment: @DonThousand Didn't notice such a very similar question was popped up so recently on Math.SE (though technically it has a different domain). IMHO, a math question may go Math or Puzzling, but Math is better if the OP doesn't know the solution, and Puzzling is better if OP knows the solution *and* that the solution is interesting.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Of course, $x=0$ is an answer, so let's look for non-zero ones from now on. If the given expression is a perfect square, so is

> four times the number, which is $4x^4+4x^3+4x^2+4x+4$.

Now we try to estimate it by "nearby" perfect squares.

> In particular, the square of $(2x^2+x)$ is $4x^4+4x^3+x^2$, which is "obviously" too small. But the square of $(2x^2+x+2)^2$ is $4x^4+4x^3+9x^2+4x+4$, and that's "obviously" too big. Thus the only possibility is the perfect square between them, $(2x^2+x+1)^2$. Solving the equation $(2x^2+x+1)^2=4x^4+4x^3+4x^2+4x+4$ by usual methods, we get $x=3$ and $x=-1$ as the only roots.

One could rightly object against the "obviously"s above since we are dealing with possibly negative numbers here. Fortunately, this is easily settled:

> We see that $$(4x^4+4x^3+4x^2+4x+4)-(2x^2+x)^2=\frac13 (3x+2)^2+\frac83>0,$$ and that $$(4x^4+4x^3+4x^2+4x+4)-(2x^2+x+2)^2=-5x^2<0$$for non-zero $x$, so the above bounds are all legal.

Thus all the possible $x$'s are

> 0,-1, and 3.

Comment: In retrospect, there was no need to look at positives and negatives separately: the key argument works nicely for general non-zero x. Oh well.

Comment: The answer is correct, and this proof (even with unnecessary case split) seems more elegant than the reference solution!

Comment: Edited to get rid of unnecessary casework and add some more explanation.

Comment: @Ankoganit How did you come up with the idea to multiply the polynomial by 4?

Comment: @pajonk when I tried to estimate the square root of the original thing with trinonials, I ran into fractions: x^2+x/2+1 and the like. The only point of scaling up by 4 was to get rid of the fractions.

Comment: @Bubbler Could you add the refence solution (as community wiki maybe)?

Comment: @BmyGuest Done.

Comment: So, I understood that the numbers we are looking for will be greater than  $(2x^2+x)$ and less than $(2x^2+x+2)$ . But, how do we know that they compulsorily  have to solve the equation : $(2x^2+x+1)^2=4x^4+4x^3+4x^2+4x+4$ and any number that does not satisfy this equation, cannot be the number we are looking for.

Comment: @HemantAgarwal The only integer between those two is $2x^2+x+1$, so the square root has to be equal to $2x^2+x+1$. Plus, its square us supposed to be $4x^4+4x^3+4x^2+4x+4$, hence the equation.

Answer (score 5):

### Reference solution

Start by

> setting the equation $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1 = y^2$ for some integers $x,y$ and multiplying both sides by four: $$ 4x^4+4x^3+4x^2+4x+4 = (2y)^2 $$

Then, observe that

> $$(2x^2+x)^2 = 4x^4+4x^3+x^2 \\ (2x^2+x+1)^2 = 4x^4+4x^3+5x^2+2x+1$$ so we can rewrite the equation in two ways: $$ (2y)^2 = (2x^2+x)^2 + 3x^2+4x+4 \\ (2y)^2 = (2x^2+x+1)^2 - (x^2-2x-3) = (2x^2+x+1)^2 - (x+1)(x-3) $$

Since there is no square number between two consecutive square numbers,

> it follows that $(2y)^2$ cannot be a square number if $3x^2+4x+4>0$ and $(x+1)(x-3)>0$. The former is always true (since $3x^2+4x+4 = x^2+2(x+1)^2+2$), and the latter is true if $x<-1$ or $x>3$.

Therefore, we reduce the search range to

> $-1 \le x \le 3$,

and by testing each number in this range, we conclude that the only answers are

> -1, 0, 3.

Comment: I actually find this (very slightly) more elegant than @Ankoganit's (by no means bad) solution because it doesn't split cases and because it doesn't require solving a quadradic equation. Of course all very minor things.

Comment: @PaulPanzer I felt the reference is less elegant because it involves solving a quadratic inequality with the same polynomial, and uses brute force at the end.

Comment: Did you just call checking 5 small numbers "brute force"? ;-P

Answer (score -4):

> the polynomial cannot be a square number

Proof

> Let $x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1 = y^2$ with $x, y$ integers.
>  Now let $y = ax^2 + bx + c$, since $y$ need not be more than degree 2 in $x$.
>  Therefore, $y^2 = a^2x^4 + 2abx^3 + (2ac + b^2)x^2 + 2bcx + c^2$.
>  Now we have a system of equations,
>  1 = a^2,
>  1 = 2ab,
>  1 = 2ac + b^2,
>  1 = 2bc,
>  1 = c^2,
>  which has no solution. Therefore, for integer $x$ the polynomial cannot be square.

Comment: There is a difference between being a square number and a square of a polynomial. For example, the polynomial y=5x^2+4 passes through some squares (e.g. 4 for x=0 and 9 for x=1 or -1) but is not itself a square of another polynomial (a^2=5, 2ab=0, b^2=4 has no solutions if we consider it as (ax+b)^2).

Comment: Oh I see how this argument is incorrect now